# How put service method in a interval function in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, http, service, observable

I'm trying to use interval function to execute service method every X seconds but It is not working.

The service method is:

```
getCryptocurrencyInfoBasic(): Observable<Asset>[]{
  this.cryptoinfo = [];
  this.cryptoinfo.push(this.http.get<Asset>(this.btcurl));
  this.cryptoinfo.push(this.http.get<Asset>(this.ethurl));
  this.cryptoinfo.push(this.http.get<Asset>(this.ltcurl));
return this.cryptoinfo;
```

}

Now I'm doing this:

```
info = interval(1000).pipe(
switchMap((i) => this.cryptoService.getCryptocurrencyInfoBasic()[i]),    
map(res => {res; console.log(res);}));
```

And It is printing every element of array (by console) but then It shows me this error:

**TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.**

How can I get in info variable the array with 3 http Observables to send it to HTML?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an array from the `getCryptocurrencyInfoBasic` method.

The Observable operator `map` expects an Observable input. Likewise, the `switchMap` operator takes an Observable input and expects an Observable return value (I am surprised your Typescript compiler or Intellisense aren't yelling at you yet, haha).

You'll need to modify `getCryptocurrencyInfoBasic` to return an Observable. The laziest approach would be to `return Observabke.of(this.cryptoinfo);`, but there's a lot of other opportunities for Observables to shine here.

For example, you could change `cryptoInfo` into a `Subject` and stream new values through it with `next`, or you could flatten the three `http.get`s into `cryptoInfo` with `flatMap`  or `mergeMap`.

Comment: I have tried to use Subject in service method, Could you explain me a little about Subjects?

Comment: You can check the official docs or some blog posts like this one: https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-subjects-339428a1815b  

At a high level, Subjects are a combination of `Observable`s and `Subscriber`s. They can be told to emit values outside of their own Observer logic, and are generally used to multicast values where a cold Observable stream doesn't serve the need.